# Proving Equality Regarding the Adjoint of Bounded Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I am proving the **Proposition 2.13** from *Elementary Functional Analysis* by MacCluer, mainly on c) and d)

We're given that For any $A,B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, we have
\begin{align*}
(\alpha A)^* &= \overline{\alpha}A^*, \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \tag*{c)}\\
(AB)^* &= B^*A^* \tag*{d)}
\end{align*}
where '$*$' stands for adjoint.

My attempt for c) shows something weird:
\begin{align*}
\langle (\alpha A)^*x,y\rangle = \langle x,(\alpha A)^{**}y\rangle=\langle x,\alpha Ay\rangle =\alpha\langle x,Ay\rangle
\end{align*}
whereas
\begin{align*}
\langle \overline{\alpha} A^*x,y\rangle &=\langle \overline{\alpha}x,A^{**}y\rangle\\
&=\langle \overline{\alpha}x,Ay\rangle\\
&=\overline{\alpha}\langle x,Ay\rangle
\end{align*}
How can this be?

For d), so far I have got:
\begin{align*}
\langle x,B^*A^*y \rangle &= \langle Bx,A^*y\rangle\\
&=\langle ABx,y\rangle\\
& =\langle x, (AB)^* y\rangle
\end{align*}
This shows that $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$

Comment: In complex inner spaces $(x,\alpha y)=\overline{\alpha}(x,y)$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x,y\in H$

Comment: To get c) apply $\langle (\alpha A)^*x,y\rangle =\langle x,\alpha Ay\rangle =\overline{\alpha}\langle x,Ay\rangle =\overline{\alpha}\langle A^*x,y\rangle=\langle \overline{\alpha}A^* x,y\rangle$ There is no need to use $A^{**}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle x,\alpha Ay\rangle =\overline{\alpha}\langle x,Ay\rangle$ and not $\alpha\langle x,Ay\rangle$ . That's how the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) is defined. It is not symmetric but conjugate symmetric.

Proof of $d$ is correct .

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: My attempt for c) shows something weird:
\begin{align*}
\langle (\alpha A)^*x,y\rangle = \langle x,(\alpha A)^{**}y\rangle=\langle x,\alpha Ay\rangle =\alpha\langle x,Ay\rangle
\end{align*}

The last equality is wrong.  It should be

\begin{align*}
\langle (\alpha A)^*x,y\rangle = \langle x,(\alpha A)^{**}y\rangle=\langle x,\alpha Ay\rangle =\overline {\alpha}\langle x,Ay\rangle
\end{align*}